# how to let only my server access to a webpage?

Tags: php, server

How to let only my server access to a webpage?

Maybe can do it with IP or something like that:

```
if(MyIPserver == visitedIP)  
  return true;
return false;
```

?

Note: the server accesses to a page via cron job.

Comment: Not using web requests for cron would be a good start.

Comment: don't use php to allow/deny ips. use your server's restrictions, probably using .htaccess (apache)

Comment: The proper approach is to put the File outside web root call via cli for cron

Answer (score 1):

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == 'Your server IP')
{
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

this should do magic.